# Facing error while fetching images from the editor of textarea attribute

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, product-attribute

I create a text area attribute with WYSIWYG allowed and visible on the product page.

I add this attribute to default attribute set.

I create a product and add some text and images to this attribute in this product with the WYSIWYG editor.

I enter also some text and images by the same way for the description field of the same product.

At the frontend side I can see text and images for the description field. The text area attribute appears under the description field in the additional informations part.

But I can see only the html text of the attribute, images don’t appear.

If I analyze the generated html code, I can see that the code included by the WYSIWYG editor like src="{{media url="folder/image.jpg"}} has not been parsed. The same code has been parsed for the description field.

How can I do to make this working ? Thanks for your help.

How I am fetching the data from the editor:

```
echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to process WYSIWYG content to convert short codes into its values. Use below

```
$processor = Mage::helper('cms')->getBlockTemplateProcessor();
$html = $processor->filter($_product->getResource()->getAttribute('attribute_code')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product););
echo $html;
```